# Is the usage "how many ever" correct?

Tags: word-usage

Eg : You may use it how many ever time.

I know the sentence can be phrased better but I just wanted to given an example.

So my question is, Is "how many ever" a correct usage?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say/convey.  It certainly doesn't make sense in your examples.  That is not to say that it is *never* correct, but it's certainly not common.

Comment: Eg : You may use my car **how many ever** times you want.
I want to know whether its right to use "how many ever".

Comment: You mean "**however many**".

Comment: No I meant how many ever, its a common usage in Asian countries, I just wanted to know if its right.

Comment: As I said before, it certainly **doesn't** make sense in your examples, and it is certainly **not** a common usage.  In your examples, **you need** *"however many"*.

Comment: And in common usage we would not say "however many times", but "however often" - in this case anyway.

Comment: Thanks frank & Trevor. @frank could you post that as an answer.

Comment: @frank *However often* does not have exactly the same meaning as *however many times*.

Comment: @WS2 could you explain the difference?

Comment: @WS2 Tha's why I said "in this case, anyway".

Comment: However many == total number of times; however often == frequency. In the car example, they're effectively the same as you can use the car multiple times per day. However, if you had something that could only be used once per day, then "however often" wouldn't be strictly valid as you *can't* use it as often as you'd like.

Comment: oh. So what would be the appropriate usage then?

Comment: @AniMenon If I had a bag of sweets, and was feeling generous, I might say *you can take however many you like*. *How often* would not work in that instance. But if I said *You can have coffee from the machine however many times per day you want*. It would be very close in meaning to say *You can have coffee however often you want* - but the meanings would not be identical - even then.

Comment: @WS2, Nice examples. Right on spot.

Comment: There are many contexts where the sequence "how many ever" could be perfectly correct and idiomatic.  The context of the first sentence, however, is not one of them.

Comment: How many times have you done it today?  How many this year?  How many ever?

Answer (score 2):

As several commenters have observed above, the standard form in U.S. and British English (at least) of a wording of the type "You may use it how many ever times you like" is "You may use it however many times you like," where "however many" has the meaning "as many."

Although the poster of the question reports that expressions of the form "how many ever times" are "a common usage in Asian countries," the vast majority of matches for "how many ever" in Google Books and Elephind newspaper searches involve instances where the author is using the phrase at the beginning of a rhetorical question of the form "how many [people] ever..." This is not the form of the expression that the OP asks about.

The one instance where a Google Books match does involve use of "how many ever" in the relevant sense has a special excuse for its formulation. From Nora Roberts, [*Daring to Dream*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9gxTgDeY23AC&pg=PT205&dq=%22how+many+ever%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvyrmY48DQAhVUzGMKHSnRDtsQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22how%20many%20ever%22&f=false) (1996):

> “We need to talk about it,” she repeated.
>
> “I haven't asked you any questions, Margo. Whoever, **how many ever**, have been in your life before, there's only one now. There's only me.”

The normal U.S. English wording here would be "however many have been in your life before..." but the author was unwilling to use that wording immediately after the word *whoever* in a parallel construction—presumably because she liked having both parallel elements end with *ever* and perhaps because the rhythmic pattern of "whoever, how many ever" seemed less awkward to her than the rhythmic stress of "whoever, however many."

In any case, the Roberts example stands alone in my database searches as an example in which "how many ever" is used in the sense of "however many." If English speakers in parts of Asia colloquially use "how many ever" in the same sense, their usage has not made much of an impression on the digital libraries I consulted.